# Missing space and extra comma in search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, user-interface

A couple of days ago I saw an edit of a post essentially only changing the team address to/from stackexchange.com. I couldn't remember which way, so I [searched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=team%40stackexchange.com) for it and got this back:

[image]

A space is missing after both the `for`s and the `,` at the end should probably be a `.`.

(As the reply indicates you'll need to search for the address without "" to reproduce this.)

Comment: Added a link to the page, just so lazier people than me can click!

Comment: Could not find results, but shows 27 results. Meta SO isn't a very good liar!

Comment: Never saw that behavior, maybe some experiment??

Comment: @gitsitgo I almost added a similar remark to my original question, as the text does seem non-sensical. The point here is obviously the quotes. [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22team@stackexchange.com%22) search-string won't reproduce it as it will search with the quotes in the first try.

Comment: @AndersUP Yeah, I was doing some repro test case earlier and noticed that as well. Also they seem to do some special parsing for team@stackexchange.com specifically, because if you search for any other email, it will just search for the string with the '@' removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

Fixed in the next build (rev 2013.9.27.1039).

Comment: You still have a comma at the end. I'm not sure that's intentional, but I'm not going to open a new question for that. ;)

Comment: @AndersUP - Frankly, not sure if it is intentional. Probably not.